# For loop object reference while GC

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have doubt on java reference while GC. inside for loop how to handle object reference.

**Code Ref#1**

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
for(int i=1; i<100; i++) {
  MyObject a = new MyObject();
  myList.add(a); 
}
```

**Code Ref#2**

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
MyObject a = null;
for(int i=1; i<100; i++) {
  a = new MyObject();
  myList.add(a); 
}
```

which code ref is correct for GC. as per my undstanding both are correct. is there any difference while GC ?.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to garbage-collect in either case, so there cannot possibly be any GC-related difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference as the lifecycle of `a` is exactly the same in your two examples.

Something like this could make a difference:

```
for(int i=1; i<100; i++) {
    a = new MyObject();
    // use a without referencing it
    a = null; // GC can collect
    // do other stuff not using a, which can be collected by GC if necessary
}
```